# How do you stored a php serialized array in mysql with values that contain apostrophes?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have a listing of names, that I want to store in mysql as a serialized array (for caching purposes). Some names contain apostrophes, and for some reason won't un-serliaze properly. There is no output.

Comment: Sounds odd. What you want to cache and why not to just keep these names in mysql as a regular data?

Comment: Because I need to display the said names in several different formats. Before I just cached raw html, but thats no longer an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the serialized string prior to inserting into the database.
You *could* handle storing serialized data by[`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)ing it prior to inserting it in the database, and [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)ing it upon retrieval, but with proper escaping that is unnecessary.

Comment: oh. Are you really base64'ing data to store it in the database?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - No. I've not done that (in PHP). But theoretically, it does allow you to sidestep many caveats involved in storage of serialized strings and just 'relax'. Also, I did say 'my favourite' and not 'the be it all, end all way would be to...'. But thank's for downvoting.

Comment: +1 for mysql_real_escape_string.  base_64_encode is unnecessary if you're properly escaping.

Comment: @Frank if you read the question, there is not insert problem but unserializing one.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my humble person. But I prefer to discuss programming questions.

Comment: If you're inserting and selecting correctly, unserialization should work without issue.  If unserializing is failing, then you're probably not storing/retrieving data correctly.